# ScriptBundle - C# - add index in GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scriptbundle

how can I add GET to script in ScriptBundle ?

example:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/baseJs").Include(
                                        "~/Scripts/index.js"
));
```

and I want to call this script:

```
 "~/Scripts/index.js?1"
```

how can I do it ?

Comment: What do you mean _add GET to script_?

Comment: add '?1' to make sure it will be update at the client

Comment: What do you mean _update at the client_?. If you have `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/baseJs")` in you view, and you modify `index.js`, then it will be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundles can be called at View(.cshtml) page like:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bundleName")
```

Replace `bundleName` with your bundle name & it will render all js files in bundle on that page.

Make sure you use render statement in start of html body.

**UPDATE:**
It's basic advantage of using bundling you can manage version of js with build. Just edit bundlename to add release number & voila all you client were forced to get bundle since it's name is different. We are doing like this.

Earlier we need to manually minify js & added version number to files names too that was configured in web config files. That was painful, bundling is cherry on cake.

Comment: it is not helping me. i need to load 'index?1' which will not happen that way. i just want to make sure the script will be forced to update at the client.

Comment: thank you, but thats not my target. i cannot put versions to all scripts and .css

Comment: No need to put version in any file names, changing bundle name with refactor will do the required.

Comment: works great, thanks :-)